# Installing Django in a Virtualenv means that i have to re-install it everytime I make another project?

Tags: python, django, installation, virtualenv

Sorry if this is an obvios or dump question but the thing is that i've been having problems with the installation of Djandgo, and the virtualenvs.

I'm a windows 10 user and I've following a series of tutorials of Django in wich they create a virtualenv an inside of it, using pip, they proceed with the installation of the framework.

The problem is that, I drop the old project or virtualenv wich had Django installed and started a new one, a new virtualenv (creating a new folder and typing virtualenv .), and reinstalled django on it but now, when i go throught the cmd to the directory

J:\project2\Scripts\django-admin.py

I receive and error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "J:\project2\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 2, in 
>       from django.core import management ImportError: No module named django.core

is it because I re-installed again Django in another new virtualenv?

Thanks to all :)

Comment: You need to provide some more details to make your question clear, like what is the `J:\project2` directory (is it a virtualenv?) But overall yes, the idea is to create different virtualenvs for different projects, and install Django in each virtualenv. See http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/

Answer (score 0):

you must activete that new venv ...Scripts/activate.py and enjoy
...and install inside venv django, after that go to you project and run 'python manage.py runserver
thats all